# Android programming, Background task (Context) in background task cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, background-task

i need some help trying to figure this out, it worked previously but after changing a couple of codes, it might be an issue. Maybe because i change over from fragment to activities.

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View v) {

                if (name.getText().toString().equals("") || email.getText().toString().equals("") || pw.getText().toString().equals("")) {


                    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =
                            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please check and fill in all the fields");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    //displaying of alert dialog
                    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                //checking pw and confirm pw
                else if (!pw.getText().toString().equals(pwConf.getText().toString())) {

                    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =
                            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Your passwords are not matching");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            pw.setText("");
                            pwConf.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

                else{
                    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
                    backgroundTask.execute("register", name.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), pw.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

yep so it's at the setting of Background task = new Background task, it is showing an error stating "Background task (context) in Background task cannot be applied to ().

Here's my backgroundtask class.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    android.content.Context ctx;
    android.app.Activity activity;
    android.app.ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String register_url = "http://10.0.2.2/mydb/register.php";
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder;


    public BackgroundTask(android.content.Context ctx) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (android.app.Activity)ctx;

    }
```

Comment: also the lightbuild assists me to remove the 1st parameter in the constructor, which is Context ctx.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor requires a Context. Change

```
BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
```

to

```
BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getActivity());
```